Python with open "replace" creating duplicate lines
I am trying to search through a .c script and replace several strings with a float. It's easy to do when I only want to replace one string. Problem is I have several different strings that all appear once, that need to be replaced by different information.
I believe my mistake is in the "for lines in file in". Every time I add a new line in this loop where I try to replace a string, it adds an extra duplicate line to my code. I am struggling to find a way to replace all the strings in the one loop.
Here is the part of my code where I am having problems:
with open(input_file, 'r') as filein:
    with open(MATERIAL_LIST[number]+'.c', 'w+') as fileout:
        for line in filein:
            fileout.write(line.replace('TBOIL_VAL', str(BOILING_POINT[number])))
            fileout.write(line.replace('THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY_VAL', str(THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY[number])))
            
            

    fileout.close()
filein.close()

Thanks for your time
I tried to look at each line in my filein, and replace strings with different floats as my fileout. I can successfully do this with one string replacement, but anything over one and duplicates come into play.

Call fileout.write() once only: fileout.write(line.replace(..., ...).replace(..., ...)).

Side comment -- the whole point of using with open ... is that you DON'T need to call close() afterwards.

Simply don't call fileout.write each time you replace something in the line, only call it once after all replacements.
In order to achieve that, you can store the intermediate results in a variable (which can have the same name as the original line, if you don't need the original line anymore).
line = line.replace('TBOIL_VAL', str(BOILING_POINT[number]))
line = line.replace('THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY_VAL', str(THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY[number]))
# ...
fileout.write(line)

Alternatively, you can call .replace repeatedly on the result of the previous .replace directly in a single expression which you pass to fileout.write (the line breaks before each .replace are only for better readability but they are not strictly needed):
fileout.write(
    line
    .replace('TBOIL_VAL', str(BOILING_POINT[number]))
    .replace('THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY_VAL', str(THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY[number]))
    # ...
)

